# How to install firebird server using a wix installer

Tags: wix, installation, firebird, silent-installer, merge-module

I am required to install firebird super server on windows as a service, as a part of my application installation through wix for windows machines.

The machines might have a another firebird instance, usually default instance running, thus must be installed on a different port. User should not see any dialogues and installation should happen in the background.

I am able to do the installation through instsvc, installing firebird on a different port with a new instance name. However on windows you get the file execution security warning for instsvc execution. Thus I was looking in to http://www.mwasoftware.co.uk/firebird-msm merge modules but, it does not provide me with information on how to install on a different port/service name(if required).

Could you please provide me info on how to install firebird using wix, so that it would install firebird as apart of my wix installation, on a specified port, without obstructing existing installations, and no interaction from the user.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebird installer only installs the service as the default instance with the default port. If you want to run on a different port and use a different servicename, then you need to change the port in firebird.conf yourself, and execute `instsvc` with an alternative servicename.

Answer (score 0):

What I got from the merge module dev. While I havent tried the solution yet, seems to be straight forward.

> The build scripts including WIX scripts are all available for
>   download. The direct link is:
>
> http://www.mwasoftware.co.uk/download-msm/download/8-current-version/130-msm-build
>
> To install a (possible) second server, you should do two things:
>
> 1. Build use a modified firebird.conf
> 2. Change all the UUIDs so that the package is unique.
>
> You will also need to copy the build251.bat script and update the
>   environment variables to the Firebird version you are using. See also
>   readme.htm.